# Creating a pandas time series datetime with sub-milisecond datetime and downsampling it

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series

So I am quite a novice to pandas timeseries but I think I need it for some applications.

I have a dataset of an voltage recording which was sampled at a rate of 2500Hz for an hour
it needs to be downsampled to 1500hz.

How can I A) create a datetime index/object for this data and B) downsample it to 1500Hz?

**EDIT (here is an example):**

```
original_hz = 1/2500 # 2500 hz
downsample_to_hz = 1/1500 # 1500 hz

# 1 second time index at the two sampling frequencies
time_2500hz = np.arange(0, 1, original_hz) 
time_1500hz = np.arange(0, 1, downsample_to_hz)

# example sine wave of recording at 2500hz
amplitude   = np.sin(time)
```

How do I downsample and interpolate amplitude so it lines up with
the time index from sampling at 1500hz?

I would like to use pandas timeseries (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html) for this but examples in numpy will also be useful.

**EDIT**
Including this as I feel others may find it useful.  There is a scipy function that almost does what I want:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html however the value, q the decimation factor, needs to be an int which does not work for all situation. Quite a shame really don't see why they limited the function like that.

Comment: Have you tried `resample`? Please make an effort to provide a reproducible example (DataFrame constructor ideally). This can probably be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I'm kinda confused by the whole syntax I could do a simple numpy arrange statement of 100 random values but not sure how that would help.

Comment: As long as you provide code to reproduce a faithful example, and the matching expected output, this brings clarity. You also need to define **how** you want to resample (which aggregation)

Comment: Ok I'll make something quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and [`resample.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.interpolate.html):

```
# making a sin wave for the example to be more visual
# not needed in the real case!
amplitude   = np.sin(time_2500hz)

# set up DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'signal': amplitude})
# Timedelta index at 2500Hz
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index/2500, unit='s')

# calculate resampling factor
# must be an integer so use microseconds
rate_microsec = 1_000_000//1500

# resample with interpolation
df2 = df.resample(f'{rate_microsec}U').interpolate()
```

Interpolated output:

```
                          signal
0 days 00:00:00         0.000000
0 days 00:00:00.000666  0.000664
0 days 00:00:00.001332  0.001328
0 days 00:00:00.001998  0.001992
0 days 00:00:00.002664  0.002656
...                          ...
0 days 00:00:00.996336  0.803052
0 days 00:00:00.997002  0.803052
0 days 00:00:00.997668  0.803052
0 days 00:00:00.998334  0.803052
0 days 00:00:00.999000  0.803052

[1501 rows x 1 columns]
```

2500Hz data before `resampling`:

```
                          signal
0 days 00:00:00         0.000000
0 days 00:00:00.000400  0.000400
0 days 00:00:00.000800  0.000800
0 days 00:00:00.001200  0.001200
0 days 00:00:00.001600  0.001600
...                          ...
0 days 00:00:00.998000  0.840389
0 days 00:00:00.998400  0.840605
0 days 00:00:00.998800  0.840822
0 days 00:00:00.999200  0.841038
0 days 00:00:00.999600  0.841255

[2500 rows x 1 columns]
```

##### addendum

Output of my approach on the example of your other question (8643 rows input) for an output of 5191 rows (NB. the "time" column is also resampled, which might be unwanted but can easily be fixed with `.assign(time=lambda d: range(len(d)))`).

```
                            time  channel1  channel2  channel3
0 days 00:00:00            0.000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
0 days 00:00:00.000666     1.665 -0.000011 -0.000044 -0.000022
0 days 00:00:00.001332     3.330 -0.000022 -0.000088 -0.000044
0 days 00:00:00.001998     4.995 -0.000033 -0.000132 -0.000066
0 days 00:00:00.002664     6.660 -0.000044 -0.000176 -0.000088
...                          ...       ...       ...       ...
0 days 00:00:03.453876  8325.000 -0.054687 -0.218749 -0.109374
0 days 00:00:03.454542  8325.000 -0.054687 -0.218749 -0.109374
0 days 00:00:03.455208  8325.000 -0.054687 -0.218749 -0.109374
0 days 00:00:03.455874  8325.000 -0.054687 -0.218749 -0.109374
0 days 00:00:03.456540  8325.000 -0.054687 -0.218749 -0.109374

[5191 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: So I tried to create a minimum example for this question but this did not work.  my real dataframe has 7466712 samples at a rate of 2500 hz and I need to downsample and interpolate the signal to a rate of 1500 Hz.  When i apply your solution it reduces my dataframes index to 1500 rows.  This is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you share the real dataset?

Comment: https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/LFP_data_from_Steinmetz_et_al_2019/9727895   you want the Tatum_2017-12-09_K1_g0_t0.imec.lf.bin.

Comment: The code to open it in python is:  with open(r'../LFP/Tatum_2017-12-09_lfp/Tatum_2017-12-09_K1_g0_t0.imec.lf.bin', 'rb') as fid:
    probe_K0_2500hz = np.fromfile(fid, np.int16).reshape((-1, 385))

Comment: TO be honest I'm not even sure I need pandas datetime but I need to interpolate this down to what it would be had it been sampled at 1500 hz and I'm at a loss at how to do so.

Comment: Also please note the real dataset has 385 channels, you can try just working with one at first, so when you load the data it will be a (7466712 , 385) shaped numpy array.  So it's time, channel

Comment: @Angus I have to say it took forever to download the data and then I got busy. I'll see if I can have a look tomorrow (if I don't forget...)

Comment: No pressured I'm going post another question that better illustrates the issue.  I think having an example that was exactly 1 second long was misleading.  Also pandas datetime may not be necessary.  If you get around to it it would be appreciated but don't feel you have to.

Comment: I saw your new question and applied my answer on it. It gives a resampled DataFrame of 5191 rows, for a input of 8643. I don't understand your "*When i apply your solution [on a larger input] it reduces my dataframes index to 1500 rows*", are you sure your followed the logic correctly?

Comment: I copy pasted your code but instead of using the generated sin waves I used the real data and that's what it did it.  It turning it into a 1501 by channel array.

Comment: @AngusCampbell forget about the sin wave, I just added this to have a more visual example, run the code without it and it should work fine.

Comment: Man I had the sign wave in my example in the question I know the sin wave is not important.  I'm saying I used your code exactly, verbatim, but instead of amplitude or signal I ran it on the real data which is ~7 million samples long.  And the code trimmed it to 1501 samples.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, it shouldn't trim and doesn't in my tests… Can you provide the full code you used? Anyway got the big dataset now, giving it a try

Comment: Ah you're right I found the bug.  When I had copied and pasted I left the line probe_K0_1500hz =  df.resample(f'{rate_microsec}U').interpolate()   when it should have been probe_K0_1500hz = probe_K0_2500hz.resample(f'{rate_microsec}U').interpolate()

My appologies.

Comment: OUt of curiosity what do the f and the U do?

Comment: OK, good news, so I'll stop the calculation as it's putting my computer on the knees… the f is for a f-string and the `U` is the unit for microseconds (you could use `us` I think). As `resample` needs an integer formula as string this is a way to write `'666U'` automatically

Comment: Do you still need the other question?

Comment: No I will delete it.

Comment: You can leave it if you want a pure numpy/scipy solution, but maybe link to this question and make it clear that you have a pandas answer to avoid duplicates ;)

Comment: I just deleted it but maybe I will repost it.  It would be good to have that as well.

Comment: p.s. your solution crashed my kernel lol I will try it on a better server I have access to maybe my PC just can't handle it. haha. thanks

Comment: Well, it's a 6GB dataset, probably bigger in memory once loaded… and some more for the DataFrame and output… you need to have enough RAM ;)

Comment: My university gives us access to some pretty high performance PCs so I'm going to try it on there.  Do you think its even possible to run it on your average PC at all?